# Get param on another page and edit : Vue, Axios, Django, Python

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I would like to retrieve the data passed as a parameter via the route and make one of the modifications, but I can't.

This is my `Python-Django` code

```
# CompanyApi
@csrf_exempt
def companyApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method == "GET":
        companies = Companies.objects.all()
        # companies = Companies.objects.first()
        # companies = Companies.objects.order_by("company_id").first()
        companies_serializer = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True)
        # companies_serializer = CompanySerializer(companies)
        return JsonResponse(companies_serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        company_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        companies_serializer = CompanySerializer(data=company_data)
        if companies_serializer.is_valid():
            companies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add", safe=False)
    elif request.method == "PUT":
        company_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        company = Companies.objects.get(company_id=id)
        # company = Companies.objects.get(company_id=company_data["company_id"])
        companies_serializer = CompanySerializer(company, data=company_data)
        if companies_serializer.is_valid():
            companies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Update")
    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        company = Companies.objects.get(company_id=id)
        company.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully", safe=False)
```

This is my code is my `CompanyEdit` page

```
<script setup>
import axios from "axios";
import { computed, ref, onMounted, reactive } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import CardBoxModal from "@/components/CardBoxModal_JTO.vue";
import FormField from "@/components/FormField.vue";
import FormControl from "@/components/FormControl.vue";
import BaseButton from "@/components/BaseButton.vue";
import SectionMain from "@/components/SectionMain.vue";
import CardBoxWidget from "@/components/CardBoxWidget.vue";
import CardBox from "@/components/CardBox.vue";

const modalOneActive = ref(false);


const form = reactive({
  company_id: "",
  company_name: "",
  company_email: "",
  company_phone: "",
  company_address: "",
  company_city: "",
  company_zip_code: "",
  company_logo: "",
});

const theCompany = reactive({
  company_name: "",
  company_email: "",
  company_phone: "",
  company_address: "",
  company_city: "",
  company_zip_code: "",
  company_logo: "",
});


const companies = computed(() => {
  return useCompanies.companies;
});


const route = useRoute();

const companyName = route.params.company_name;
console.log(companyName);


axios
  .get("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "company" + route.params.company_name)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.theCompany = response.data;
  });

onMounted(() => {
  fillChartData();
  return numberOfCompanies, getCompany, theCompany;
  // console.log(route.params.company_id);
  // return numberOfCompanies, firstElement;
  // company = this.company;
});
</script>

<template>
  <LayoutAuthenticated>
    <SectionMain>
      <CardBox>
        <FormField label="Noms & Email">
          <FormControl
            id="company_name"
            v-model="form.company_name"
            name="company_name"
            :icon="mdiOfficeBuilding"
            placeholder="Nom de la compagnie"
            required
          />
          <FormControl
            id="company_email"
            v-model="form.company_email"
            name="company_email"
            type="email"
            :icon="mdiMail"
            placeholder="Email de la compagnie"
            required
          />
        </FormField>

        <FormField label="Adresse & Téléphone">
          <FormControl
            id="company_address"
            v-model="form.company_address"
            name="company_address"
            :icon="mdiMapMarker"
            placeholder="Adresse de la compagnie"
            required
          />
          <FormControl
            id="company_phone"
            v-model="form.company_phone"
            name="company_phone"
            :icon="mdiPhone"
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Téléphone de la compagnie"
            required
          />
        </FormField>

        <FormField label="Ville & Code postal">
          <FormControl
            id="company_city"
            v-model="form.company_city"
            name="company_city"
            :icon="mdiCity"
            placeholder="Ville de la compagnie"
            required
          />
          <FormControl
            id="company_zip_code"
            v-model="form.company_zip_code"
            name="company_zip_code"
            :icon="mdiPost"
            placeholder="Code postal de la compagnie"
            required
          />
        </FormField>

        <!-- Buttons footer -->
        <BaseButtons class="flex justify-center">
          <BaseButton
            :icon="mdiUpdate"
            class="mr-2"
            type="submit"
            color="jt_orders"
            label="Update"
          />
          <BaseButton
            :icon="mdiCancel"
            class="ml-2"
            color="danger"
            outline
            label="Cancel"
          />
        </BaseButtons>
      </CardBox>
    </SectionMain>
  </LayoutAuthenticated>
</template>
```

This my `index.js` from router

```
  {
    meta: {
      title: "Your Company",
    },
    path: "/company/:company_name",
    name: "singleCompany",
    component: () => import("@/views/jt_orders_views/CompanyEdit.vue"),
  },
```

Button to `CompanyEdit`

```
<BaseButton
   color="jt_orders"
   :icon="mdiPencil"
   small
   :to="{
    name: 'singleCompany',
    params: { company_name: company.company_name },
   }"
/>
```

I manage to recover the company_name, but I would like to recover all the elements/data of the company table in order to make modifications.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: One solution could be: fetch the company detail in the edit page whenever the `company_name` param changes in the 'singleCompany` route. Or if that is expensive, route meta could be populated with the whole comany object. But that will not work if user explicitly browses to the edit page.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. Do you have an example from which I could use to manage my case please ?. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added answer with a raw example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a detail view in your API

```py
def companyApi(request, id=0):
  if id == 0 and request.method == "GET":
    # return list view
  if id > 0 and request.method == "GET"
    # return detail view
```

Now in you frontend EditPage:

```js
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const companyData = ref({})
watch(() => route.params.id, (v) => {
  fetchCompanyDetail()
})

const fetchCompanyDetail() {
  axios.get(`company/${Route.params.id}`)
    .then(res => {companyData.value = res.data})
}
</script>
```

Here I've used id as a param for your router (not company name) because the fetch API takes ID. You can configure the API to take in company_name and do the same for the vue  router param.